# Secure way to deploy Application on Windows Server 2016 + Apache / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ssl

I am currently working on the release of my project management software to the internet. It is my first tool that I am going to deploy in the www and I am concerned about some Security Factors. At the moment the tool is running on Apache Port 80 (https is to be done) with MySQL and PHP. I got myself a domain name which links back to the public IP of my Windows Server on which Port 80 is open for access.
I am now thinking about deploying a letsencrypt certificate in combination with the win-acme letsencrypt client. 
Can the procedure be considered as safe? I would be happy if you could provide me some feedback or improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Let's encrypt for many websites. I have never faced any problems with it. Just make sure you install it correctly.

I suggest using a Firewall and an SSH connection with strong passwords. Setup your Firewall to allow HTTPS incoming connections(PORT 443). You can deny HTTP connections if you want and allow specific IP addresses and port ranges.

Once you do it, it will depend on how efficient your code is. One of the common web hacking techniques is SQL injection. I suggest using PDO.

Hope it helps!